# Flutter/Dart - Format Duration to show just Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds?

Tags: flutter, dart, duration, converters

I've got the following duration to string;

```
  Duration(milliseconds: value).toString())
```

It produces a string that looks like this with hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds;

```
  0:00:02.658374
```

How can I get the string to look like this with only seconds and milliseconds?

```
 02.65
```

I only want two places for milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to convert from string, we can use `.substring(5, 10)` here

**Explained**
in our `Duration().toString()`, it provides `0:00:02.658374`. Using SubString we are getting text from 5 to 10th index. But we can't use this approach while we add hours. But it will work while we stay with seconds and  rest of it.

```
 final time = Duration( seconds: 2, microseconds: 658374);
  print(time.toString().substring(5, 10));
```

[image]
I would rather say, don't parse like this. It may cause some errors in the future. Instead of getting to String directly, get `Duration`.
More about parse from Duration, [you can check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68680926/10157127)

Does it solve in your case?

Comment: the problem is; I'm trying to convert a duration that's already a string.

Comment: Then you can use `substring` from my answer. does it solve in your case?

Comment: Actually that worked! Can you put that as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: If the `Duration` is, say, 62 seconds, then blindly returning a substring like this will result in `'02.00'` instead of `'62.00'`.

Comment: Yes, 62 is beyond second. I mention it above.

Answer (score 4):

Try as follows (use `.inSeconds` , `.inMilliseconds` etc. property), example:

```
log(Duration(milliseconds: 2).toString());
log(Duration(milliseconds: 3).inSeconds.toString());
log(Duration(milliseconds: 4).inMilliseconds.toString());
log(Duration(milliseconds: 5).inMicroseconds.toString());
```

then becomes:

```
log((Duration(milliseconds: 2658).inMilliseconds * 0.001).toStringAsFixed(2));
```

Comment: I don't follow. How does this convert 0:00:02.658374 to 02.65 ?

Comment: How much is the given millisec you are passing?

Comment: 2658 milliseconds needs to look like 02:65

Comment: I hope you understand how (now after updating answer) .

Answer (score 4):

If you want just seconds and milliseconds, I would do:

```dart
String prettyDuration(Duration duration) {
  var seconds = duration.inMilliseconds / 1000;
  return '${seconds.toStringAsFixed(2)}s';
}
```

The above should output strings such as `2.65s`, `62.65s`, `0.65s`, `0.00s`.

If you want minutes, seconds, and milliseconds (as asked by your question title):

```dart
String prettyDuration(Duration duration) {
  var seconds = (duration.inMilliseconds % (60 * 1000)) / 1000;
  return '${duration.inMinutes}m${seconds.toStringAsFixed(2)}s';
}
```

The above should output strings such as `1m2.65s`, `62m0.65s`, `0m0.00s`.

A more complicated version that handles days and hours and that omits components that are 0:

```dart
String prettyDuration(Duration duration) {
  var components = <String>[];
  
  var days = duration.inDays;
  if (days != 0) {
    components.add('${days}d');
  }
  var hours = duration.inHours % 24;
  if (hours != 0) {
    components.add('${hours}h');
  }
  var minutes = duration.inMinutes % 60;
  if (minutes != 0) {
    components.add('${minutes}m');
  }

  var seconds = duration.inSeconds % 60;
  var centiseconds =
      (duration.inMilliseconds % 1000) ~/ 10;
  if (components.isEmpty || seconds != 0 || centiseconds != 0) {
    components.add('$seconds');
    if (centiseconds != 0) {
      components.add('.');
      components.add(centiseconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0'));
    }
    components.add('s');
  }
  return components.join();
}
```

The above should output strings such as `1d2h3m2.65s`, `1d2m3s`, `0s`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe prettier to do this. It does also round the number correctly instead of just cutting of places:

```
void main() {
  print(durationToString(const Duration(milliseconds: 2658))); // 02:66
}

String durationToString(Duration duration) => (duration.inMilliseconds / 1000)
    .toStringAsFixed(2)
    .replaceFirst('.', ':')
    .padLeft(5, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    String seconds = (duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    String milliseconds = ((duration.inMilliseconds % 1000) ~/ 100).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return '$seconds.$milliseconds';
```

Or

```
    String time = ((duration.inMilliseconds / 1000)).toStringAsFixed(2).padLeft(5, '0');
    return time;
```

Both of them will return you `02.65`