# How to change value of timer on gesture tap?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, timer

So I ran into another problem with my timer.

I have a sized box, and when I tap on it I would want the timer to change the value from 5 minutes to 15 minutes (Or best, when I tap the first time it will increase from 5 minutes > 10 minutes on the second tap 15 minutes on the third tap to 20 minutes and on fourth to 25 minutes)
For this to happen the timer should be not active(The user can only change it when the timer is not running) -- But I'm running into the problem of "Undefined name 'isRunning'." from my final in another widget

Here is my code (Also side question, currently the timer only displays seconds, how can I make it display the actual 5 minutes as in 5:00)

```
class timeryypage extends State<timerry> {
  static const maxSeconds = 5;
  int seconds = maxSeconds;
  Timer? timer;

  void resetTimer() => setState(() => seconds = maxSeconds);

  void startTimer({bool reset = true}) {
    if (reset) {
      resetTimer();
    }
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      //add here instead seconds say minutes/miliseconds
      if (!mounted) // Putting this line of code with return under, fixed my issue i been having about mounted
        return;
      else if (seconds > 0) {
        setState(() => seconds--);
      } else {
        stopTimer(reset: false);
      }
    });
  }

  void stopTimer({bool reset = true}) {
    if (reset == mounted) {
      resetTimer();
    }
    setState(() => timer?.cancel());
  }

  @override
  Widget buildButtons() {
    final isRunning = timer == null ? false : timer!.isActive;
    final isCompleted = seconds == maxSeconds || seconds == 0;
    return isRunning || !isCompleted
        ? Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ButtonWidget(
                text: isRunning ? "Pause" : "Resume",
                onClicked: () {
                  if (isRunning) {
                    stopTimer(reset: false);
                  } else {
                    startTimer(reset: false);
                  }
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 12),
              ButtonWidget(text: "Cancel", onClicked: stopTimer)
            ],
          )
        : ButtonWidget(
            text: "Start Timer!",
            color: Colors.black,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            onClicked: () {
              startTimer();
            },
          );
  }

  Widget buildTimer() => SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: seconds / maxSeconds,
              //if you delete 1 - then it goes to other direction
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
              strokeWidth: 12,
              backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              onTap: () {
                if (isRunning) {
                  print("do nothing");
                } else {
                  const snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Tap'));
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                  print("tapped");
                  // later on i want to change timer from 5 minutes 10 minutes on first tap, then second tap to 15 minutes
                }
              },
              child: Center(child: buildTime()),
            ),
            //Center(child: buildTime()),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Widget buildTime() {
    if (seconds == 0) {
      return Icon(Icons.done, color: Colors.greenAccent, size: 112);
    } else {
      return Text(
        "$seconds",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 80,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Thank you so much for help!

Edit Adding extra code :

```
bool get isRunning => _timer?.isActive ?? false;
  int _seconds = 00;
  int _minutes = setminutes;
  static const setminutes = 25;
  Timer? _timer;
  var f = NumberFormat("00");

  void _stopTimer({bool reset = true}) {
    if (reset == true) {
      resetTimer();
    }
    setState(() => _timer?.cancel());
    ;
  }

  void resetTimer() => setState(() => _minutes = setminutes);

  void _startTimer({bool reset = true}) {
    if (reset) {
      resetTimer();
    }
    if (_timer != null) {
      _stopTimer();
    }
    if (_minutes > 0) {
      _seconds = _minutes * 60;
    }
    if (_seconds > 60) {
      _minutes = (_seconds / 60).floor();
      _seconds -= (_minutes * 60);
    }
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      if (!mounted)
        return;
      else if (_seconds > 0) {
        setState(() => _seconds--);
      }

      setState(() {
        if (_seconds > 0) {
          _seconds--;
        } else {
          if (_minutes > 0) {
            _seconds = 59;
            _minutes--;
          } else {
            _stopTimer(reset: false);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildButtons() {
    //final isRunning = timer == null ? false : timer!.isActive;
    final isCompleted = _minutes == setminutes || _seconds == 0;
    return isRunning || !isCompleted
        ? Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ButtonWidget(
                text: isRunning ? "Pause" : "Resume",
                onClicked: () {
                  if (isRunning) {
                    _stopTimer(reset: false);
                  } else {
                    _startTimer(reset: false);
                  }
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 12),
              ButtonWidget(
                  text: "Cancel",
                  onClicked: () {
                    _stopTimer(reset: true);
                  })
            ],
          )
        : ButtonWidget(
            text: "Start Timer!",
            color: Colors.black,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            onClicked: () {
              _startTimer();
            },
          );
  }
```

Comment: `isRunning` is a local variable to the `buildButtons` function.  If you want to refer to it outside of that function, you should make a getter (and you can slightly simplify it):  `bool get isRunning => timer?.isActive ?? false;`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!. Do you know maybe how I can make it so instead displaying "5" as in 5 seconds, it will display 5:00 (5 minutes) ? Is there some quick fix to my code or will i have to rewrite most of it somehow?

Comment: Thank you for help! I have error as in it tells me "The method 'padLeft' isn't defined for the type 'int'." Any idea :?

Comment: Thank you! Works. But when i change my static const maxSeconds for example to 120 (2 minutes) it displays 2: 120, how can I edit the code so when i put 120 seconds it will display 2:00 :? I think my entire code needs rewriting :|

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I'll just write an answer so that I can correct my mistakes. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buildTime` function creates a `Text` widget from the number of seconds. If you want to format it in some other way, you will need format the number of seconds to a `String` yourself.  For example:

```dart
var minutes = seconds ~/ 60;
var remainderSeconds = seconds % 60;
return Text('$minutes:${remainderSeconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}',
  ...);
```

Also see:

- [Find out how many days, how many hours and how many minutes in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69362715/)
- [Flutter/Dart - Format Duration to show just Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68682573/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it! -- One question as I can't find answer on google, how can I change my static const of maxSeconds when I press onClick ? For example add 300 more seconds ?

Comment: `const` means it cannot be changed.  If you want to change it, don't use `const`.

Comment: I made it into var, and "late" int seconds. Problem I'm having now is that when I click the button to add more seconds, it doesn't update the second/timer on the screen automatically, but when I press start timer then it runs from the updated timer which added extra seconds. How can I make it so when I click the button and it adds the extra time it shows right away?

Comment: Are you add more seconds, do you do so via a call to `setState`?  If you don't, then the widget tree won't be rebuilt.  You also should make separate questions for individual problems.

Comment: I just put it `maxSeconds = 1000;` on gesture tap --- Ok will make it into separate question

Comment: Ok, i managed to do it `void addmoreseconds() {
    setState(() {
      maxSeconds = 600;
      resetTimer();
    });
  }`