# Find out how many days, hours and minutes left until exact DateTime

Tags: flutter, datetime, time

I tried to do something like this but failed. I was able to code a single day, but not how many hours and minutes are left.

Example picture:

[image: example picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something similar for a personal project, this is the snippet. It's a helper function to which you must give `ms`, being, `EndDateInMs - StartDateInMs`. There's also a `TimeFrame` type, but you don't need it; just take the logic for calculating the weeks/days/hours/minutes.

```
import '../enums/enums.dart';

Map<TimeFrame, int> msConverter(double ms) {
  int minutes;
  int hours;
  int days;
  int weeks;

  const msInWeek = 6.048e+8;
  weeks = (ms / msInWeek).floor();

  final msLeftForDays = ms - (msInWeek * weeks);
  const msInDay = 8.64e+7;
  days = (msLeftForDays / msInDay).floor();

  final msLeftForHours = msLeftForDays - (msInDay * days);
  const msInHour = 3.6e+6;
  hours = (msLeftForHours / msInHour).floor();

  final msLeftForMinutes = msLeftForHours - (msInHour * hours);
  const msInMinute = 60000;
  minutes = (msLeftForMinutes / msInMinute).round();

  return <TimeFrame, int>{
    TimeFrame.Weeks: weeks,
    TimeFrame.Days: days,
    TimeFrame.Hours: hours,
    TimeFrame.Minutes: minutes,
  };
}
```

Comment: Excouse me sir, what is this "6.048e+8+" or "8.64e+7" ?

Comment: And I can't use it when I write the code.

Comment: @hypirea `6.048e+8` is a `double` represented in scientific notation (6.048 * 10^8).  With this approach, I personally would avoid using `double`s entirely and would replace the unreadable (and error-prone) magic numbers with things such as `const msInWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`.  I also would use truncating division (`~/`) instead of using `floor()`.

Comment: Sir, thank you so much. You did it. <3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a `Duration` into days, minutes, hours, and seconds, you can just do:

```dart
var days = duration.inDays;
var hours = duration.inHours % 24;
var minutes = duration.inMinutes % 60;
var seconds = duration.inSeconds % 60;
```

(If you're starting from, say, a total number of seconds instead of from a `Duration` object, you can easily construct a `Duration` object first: `Duration(seconds: totalSeconds)`.)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68685066/ for a more complex version that formats a `Duration` as a `String` of the form `1d2h3.45s`.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. <3