# Dart, get difference between two DateTimes in (Days-Hours-Minutes)?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get difference between two DateTimes in (Days-Hours-Minutes)?

```
        DateTime a = someTimeStamp.toDate();
        print(a);
        final now = DateTime.now();
        print(now);
        var difference = now.difference(a).inMilliseconds;
        print(difference);
        var dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(difference);
        print(dt);
```

it shows 1970-01-05 06:40:01.632 at the end

Comment: `difference` is a `Duration` object.  You can compute the number of days/hours/minutes/etc. from that.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68685066/ for an example.

Comment: @jamesdlin wow that was so complicated than I expected I`ll try your answer // it gives red line when I do prettyDuration(difference); it says The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Duration'. // I removed 
 .inMilliSeconds and then works thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get them like this:

```
DateTime a = DateTime(2022,3,29,4,56);
DateTime b = DateTime.now();

Duration difference = b.difference(a);

print(difference);

int days = difference.inDays;
int hours = difference.inHours % 24;
int minutes = difference.inMinutes % 60;
int seconds = difference.inSeconds % 60;

print("$days day(s) $hours hour(s) $minutes minute(s) $seconds second(s).");
```

Output:

```
103:14:07.663000
4 day(s) 7 hour(s) 14 minute(s) 7 second(s).
```